# if you have a grid of $m \times n$ squares why is the number of paths from $(1,n)$ to $(m,1)$ equal to $\binom{m+n-2 }{m - 1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider an $m \times n$ grid of unit squares, indexed by
$(i, j)$ with $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$.

Then why is the number of possible paths from $(1,n)$ to $(m,1)$ such that you  are only going down and to the right equal to $\binom{m+n-2}{m -1}$?

could someone give me some intuition for this?

This question is asked in reference to B1 question of the 2023 Putnam competition, as I do not understand how the solutions derived this result.

Answer (score 3):

The number of rights you would have to take along the path would be $m-1,$ and the amount of downs you would have to take along the path would be $n-1.$  This means that the number of paths we can possibly take is the same as the number of ways to arrange $DDD...DDDRRR...RRR$ where we have $m-1$ Rs and $n-1$ Ds.  This is equal to $C((n-1)+(m-1),m-1)=C(n+m-2,m-1)$ because all rights and all downs are indistinguishable.

Comment: This makes sense although I can't immediately see why the total number of ways to arrange DDD...DDDRRR...RRR would be C(n+m-2, m-1). I can see that the permutation would be (n+m-2)! and you would have some repeats but I find the step where eliminating the repeats would give C(n+m-2, m-1)

Comment: @244529 The positions of the $R$s form an $m-1$-subset of the $n+m-2$ possible positions.